# A beginner with a question about global sections.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme, $s_{1}$, $s_{2}$ global sections in $X$
and $\pi : \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be the blow up morphism of $X$ along $Y \subset X$ with exceptional divisor $E$.

Let $\widetilde{U} = \widetilde{X}\setminus E$ and suppose that $\overline{U}= \widetilde{X}$.  If $s_{1} = s_{2}$ in  $\widetilde{U}$  then $s_{1} = s_{2}$ in $\widetilde{X}$?

References and suggestions are welcome.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to precise what does "a section" mean to you. I guess that you are talking of a section of the structure sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X$, $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}$.

Note that for locally free sheaves (as the structure sheaves), the zero set of a section is **closed**. You can apply this to $s_1-s_2$ to obtain the result you need.

Comment: Hi, @Dominique. Yes, I was talking about a section of the structural sheaf. 
 Thanks for the help, thank you so much. I am new in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Me and my fellow beginners in algebraic geometry appreciate your response. Again, thank you very much.